# Loki's file manager repeatedly creates a random ~/.config/dconf/user file

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, dconf

As I wrote in the title, everytime I launch Loki's file manager it starts writing and deleting a random ~/.config/dconf/user file, causing an excessive disk activity.
Is there anyone experiencing the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Files stores a number of settings in the ~./config/user file (run dconf-editor and navigate to  org/pantheon/files to see them).  Some of these settings are updated in real time as you change e.g. the zoom level or show/hide hidden files.

However, I have discovered using inotifywatch that this file is continually changing, as you report, while Files is open even with no user interaction so this appears to be a bug. I will raise it in Launchpad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because I thought that I didn't post my question in the right place, I reported this error even in Launchpad to the Phanteon-files team. Can you tell me what is the right community to report such problems? Thank you.

Comment: If you are of the opinion that the problem is due to a fault or deficiency in FIles then it can be reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files (check there first that it has not already been reported).

Comment: Ok. 
Thank you very much.